# Does jinja blocks have a default parameter

Tags: html, jinja2

Is there a way to create a default entry, if a block isn't filled?

I have a template with a button that says *create*.

*myTemplate.html:*

```
<a href="#" class="btn">create</a>
```

Up until now, all pages using this template have used the test *create*, however now I would like to be able to edit that text from my page.

Usually I would add a block to the template to be overridden by the page:

*myTemplate.html:*

```
<a href="#" class="btn">{% block createString %}{% endblock %}</a>
```

*myPage.html:*

```
{% extends "myTemplate.html" %}
{% block createString %}next{% endblock %}
```

However, for this I would like to have something like a default, so that if I don't have any `createString` block in the myPage, a default string will be used.

Something like:

*myTemplate.html:*

```
<a href="#" class="btn">{% block createString %}{% default %}create
                        {% endblock %}</a>
```

In the *myPage.html* the button will say *next* while in the other files extending *myTemplate.html* the button will read *create*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was much simpler than I thought...

So in the template I just write the "default" code within the *block*.

myTemplate.html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">{% block createString %}create{% endblock %}</a>
```

So in the pages I want the *create* text I simply ignore the *createString* block, while in the pages I want to change the text I override the template block like the following.

myPage.html:

```
{% extends "myTemplate.html" %}
{% block createString %}next{% endblock %}
```